# .NET - Call Generic Method or Cast at Runtime with Type

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the following VB.NET code:

```
Private _retryMessages as Dictionary(Of Type, List(Of Object))

Private Sub RetryMessage(Of T)(message as T)
    _retryMessages(GetType(T)).Add(message)
End Sub

Private Sub Publish(Of T)(message as T)
    ' code to publish message -- dependent on T
End Sub
```

I want to create a new method that will iterate through the dictionary and call `Publish` of each message:

```
Private Sub AttemptRetryMessages()
    For Each messageType In _retryMessages.Keys
        messages = _retryMessages(messageType)
        ' now I'm lost ...
        'For Each message In messages
        '    Publish(message) '<-- System.Object
        'Next
    Next
End Sub
```

The problem is I have the type, but I'm not sure how to call `Publish` providing the proper type for the generic.  If I just call it as is then `T` is interpreted as `System.Object`.

I have complete control of the code so if there is a better way to go about this I'm open to it.  The goal is that we can have dozens of types of messages and I simply want to be able to queue them up in case the send fails.

Thanks!

Comment: I have never coded VB, however I know a few other languages.  `Private _retryMessages as Dictionary(Of Type, List(Of Object))` tells me your `_retryMessages` field will return an `Object`.  Without changing your design much I think you need to take out `(Of T)` from your `Publish` method and make it (guessing on the syntax) `Private Sub Publish(message as Object, type as Type)` and call it like `Publish(message, message.GetType())` (assuming `GetType()` is a method).

Comment: Of course if you do that then there's no need to have generic parameters to `RetryMessage.`  Let me ask you this:  Are you making the classes for `T` or will you be using types others have made?  If you're making them, I'd recommend using interfaces, instead and generic constraints if VB handles that.  If you are let me know and I'll explain how to do that.

Comment: *will return a `List` of `Object`'s.

Answer (score 0):

If Publish is the same for all of your Message Types then do the following.

1: Create a Base Class that your other Message Classes inherit from:

```
Public Class Message

    Public Sub Publish()
        'Implementation Omitted
    End Sub

End Class
```

2: Change some existing code:

```
Private _retryMessages as Dictionary(Of Type, List(Of Message))
```

3: Finally your AttemptRetryMessages() becomes:

```
Private Sub AttemptRetryMessages() 

    For Each messageList As List(Of Message) In _retryMessages.Values 
        For Each m As Message in messageList
            messageType.Publish()
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

If Publish needs to be implemented differently for each Message Type then it gets a little messier.  You'll have to use GetType() to figure 
out what kind of Message Class it is and then call the appropriate code.  If this is the case then I wouldn't use Generics, as generic methods 
are typically used for shared functionality amongst different types.  An example of which is the Dictionary Class.  It doesn't care if its a
List of Objects or a List of Messages, the dictionary functionality is the same.